# Advanced notification system (notify only about unread messages)

Tags: laravel, notifications

I'm building an application based on Laravel 5.6 with live chat functionality (uses Pushier).
I need to notify Users via email about new messages. The problem is that I should not send notification each time as message sent because user can be online and receive this message. Also if theme were 20 messages in a minute I do not need to send 20 emails, just one with "you have new messages".

My idea is:
1. on each message I have a Laravel Notification "Message received". If user online - notification deletes. So in notifications table I have notifications about unreceived messages.
2. I should run Task (e.g. each 15 min) and if there Notification(s) for User - sent email "You have unread messages". 
3. Now I have the problem that if user won't read notifications during 15 min - he will receive email again.. So I need to store in some table (or expand current notification table with mark) data about Notifications that already was emailed.

Is my approach correct?
Thanks!

Comment: Trying to figure out the same exact thing right now :)